# Simple swap on array in java gives strange result

Tags: java, arrays, swap

this is such an easy piece of code. But still the result is wrong and I just do not see why - does anyone?

With the array `int[] a = {3,1,0,2,5}` and calling it with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.swap(a, a[0], a[1])));` I get **[3, 2, 0, 1, 5]** as result. What is happening here? I expect **[1, 3, 0, 2, 5]**. - Thanks!

```
import java.util.Arrays;


    public class MyClass {


    public int[] swap(int[] array, int a, int b){
            int temp = array[a];
            array[a] = array[b];
            array[b] = temp;
            return array;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing the value instead of the index as arguments when you call the swap method? Looks to me like you should pass a, 0, 1 as args rather than a, a[0], a[1]

Comment: Absolutely, still not got a routine. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This line is calling swap with indices A[0]=3 and A[1]=1, thus swapping A[3] with A[1].

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.swap(a, a[0], a[1])));
```

Comment: Thanks, now I see it!!

Answer (score 1):

The second and third parameters should be the index of your arrays you want to swap.

```
int[] a = {3,1,0,2,5}
to swap first and second index you should call swap(a, 0, 1)
swap(a, 0, 1)
Then a becomes{1,3,0,2,5}
```

Answer (score 0):

temp becomes array[a[0]], array[3] --> 2

array[a[0]] array[3] becomes array[a[1]] becomes array[1]: --> 1

array[1] becomes 2

3 2 0 1 5

Answer (score 0):

The function expect indices, but you're passing values !
Just consider `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.swap(a, 0, 1)));` instead of `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.swap(a, a[0], a[1])));`